# Pharmaceutical solubility databases?

Tags: databases, solubility

I am looking for databases for the solubility of pharmaceuticals (small drug molecules up to 1500 g/mol MW) in a variety of pure and mixed solvents.

There is the [Handbook of solubility data for pharmaceuticals](https://www.worldcat.org/title/handbook-of-solubility-data-for-pharmaceuticals/oclc/423572634), which can be purchased. Nowadays, I would expect there to be Git repo's similar to the FreeSolv database for hydration free energies. I am finding some data, and aqueous solubilities seem much more numerous i.e., [AqSolDB](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sorkun/aqsoldb-a-curated-aqueous-solubility-dataset), but I would like data for training and testing models on solvents other than water as well.

Open source would be great.

Comment: This might be better asked on the Chemistry stack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The largest dataset I've seen for molecular solubilities, both computed solvation energies and experimental solvation free energies and $\log S$ values is [SolProp](https://zenodo.org/record/5970538#.Ys7Mmi-B1pR) by the Green group, published as part of three papers:

- [Predicting Solubility Limits of Organic Solutes for a Wide Range of Solvents and Temperatures](https://doi.org/10.1021/jacs.2c01768)
- [Group Contribution and Machine Learning Approaches to Predict Abraham Solute Parameters, Solvation Free Energy, and Solvation Enthalpy](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jcim.1c01103)
- [Transfer learning for solvation free energies: From quantum chemistry to experiments](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cej.2021.129307)

I don't remember off-hand if they include AquaSol, but that database is known to have issues with some compounds.

They explicitly do *not* include the [MNSol](https://comp.chem.umn.edu/mnsol/) database of solvation free energies because of license issues. (MNSol is not for commercial use without paid license.)

Comment: That is a nice and fresh dataset too, only a couple weeks old!

Comment: I can't remember when it went up, but I think with their preprint.

Comment: They have also posted their model: https://github.com/fhvermei/SolProp_ML and a set of web tools: https://rmg.mit.edu/database/solvation/search/